# React native app won't compile after expo package added

Tags: android, react-native

I've added expo-av package to my bare react native app. It was compiling just fine before, but after that it won't compile release apk, just debug version for emulator, which works fine. I've tried `./gradlew build --warning-mode all` in android directory and getting this error:

```
> Task :expo-constants:copyReleaseExpoConfig FAILED
w: Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build/kotlin/sessions

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':expo-constants:copyReleaseExpoConfig' (type 'Copy').
 * Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/Users/ilya/wrk/react_native/DraftAI/node_modules/expo-constants/android/src/main/assets'.
```

I have no idea what does it mean, but for some reason `react-native doctor` now says that:

```
 ✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 - Versions found: N/A
 - Version supported: 33.0.0
```

I've created new empty react native app and it wont create apk with `npx react-native build-android --mode=release` ether. It says "BUILD SUCCESSFUL", but there is no apk. `./gradlew build` from android folder works just fine. I'm buffled. Nee help

Answer (score 0):

Try to stop the running Gradle daemon and rebuild app:

```
./gradlew --stop
```